# Is it possible to store the token in react context and how we can do?

Tags: reactjs, set, local-storage, token, react-context

How we can store the token in react context and also why it is bad way for storing the token in local and session storage.?

I have suppose to do by creating create context and consuming it in our login component.

Comment: You need to put a little more clarity to your question like what exactly are you using for login.

Comment: Have a read of this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69295904/281278) for token storage methods and their pros/cons. LocalStorage is still viable, but can introduce the potential for XSS attacks so use it with caution.